# I am stuck using SQL*Loader with to_date() for one of my field of type date

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-loader

I am using a SQL*Loader to load the table from db2 to oracle DB using

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '<path><File_name>.del' 
replace
into table schema.tableName fields terminated by ','
(
col1,
col2,
col3,....
)
Rejected - Error on table schema_name.table_name, column col3.
ORA-01861: literal does not match format string.
```

As col3 is of type date, we need to convert it to oracle acceptable date format. 
Could anyone please tell me how to use the to_date() in sql loader?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example:

My test table, which will hold input data:

```
SQL> desc test
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- -------------------
 ID                                                 NUMBER
 DATUM                                              DATE

SQL>
```

Control file; note

- `to_date` function call (double quotes, proper date format mask which has to match format of data you're loading)
- the 3rd row, whose format is "invalid"

  ```
  load data 
  infile *
  replace
  into table test
  fields terminated by ','
  trailing nullcols
  ( 
  id,
  datum "to_date(:datum, 'yyyy-dd-mm')"
  )

  begindata
  1,2020-20-05
  2,2020-28-12
  3,20200215
  ```

Loading session:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> $sqlldr scott/tiger control=test20.ctl log=test20.log

SQL*Loader: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on Sri Svi 20 08:10:53 2020

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Commit point reached - logical record count 2
Commit point reached - logical record count 3

SQL> select * From test;

        ID DATUM
---------- ----------
         1 20.05.2020
         2 28.12.2020

SQL>
```

As you can see, the 3rd row wasn't loaded. Log file contents. Note the `ORA-01861` error:

```
Table TEST, loaded from every logical record.
Insert option in effect for this table: REPLACE
TRAILING NULLCOLS option in effect

   Column Name                  Position   Len  Term Encl Datatype
------------------------------ ---------- ----- ---- ---- ---------------------
ID                                  FIRST     *   ,       CHARACTER            
DATUM                                NEXT     *   ,       CHARACTER            
    SQL string for column : "to_date(:datum, 'yyyy-dd-mm')"

Record 3: Rejected - Error on table TEST, column DATUM.
ORA-01861: literal does not match format string


Table TEST:
  2 Rows successfully loaded.
  1 Row not loaded due to data errors.
  0 Rows not loaded because all WHEN clauses were failed.
  0 Rows not loaded because all fields were null.
```

---

So: make sure that all input data follow the same format mask.

Comment: I tried with the solution provided but now i am getting "ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0" may be because the format of the date in my db2 table is yyyymmdd

Comment: No problem in that; as I said: pay attention to correct date format. You'd use `"to_date(:datum, 'yyyymmdd')"`.

Comment: i used same date format
EFFDT "to_date(:EFFDT, 'yyyymmdd')",

Comment: OK. Then some data doesn't look like what Oracle expects, i.e. YYYY is something that doesn't fit into -4713 and 9999.